# How do i record videos in sections and also allow the user to delete sections(Same as instagram app)

Tags: ios, instagram, alassetslibrary, uiprogressview

I want to know if there is any control that lets me record videos and stitch them together in the similar way as the instagram app.

The video recording is being done in sections.The cross button allows the user to delete the previous section recorded.

[image]

**Questions**:

Is that a customized progress view?

How do i delete the previous sections? How do i get the urls from the ALAssets Library?

Answer (score 0):

i know the answer is too late but that helping to others..

https://github.com/rFlex/SCAudioVideoRecorder

in above link demo is similar to instagram recorder (instead delete give retake video recording), and as well as stay in background (video not delete after coming foreground) it very helpful.